# What do i use in excel to populate a list on sheet1 from data in various places on different sheets?

Tags: excel

I want data from cells in sheet 2, 3 & 4 to automatically copy over to sheet 1 (progressively filling in the next blank cell in the column specified on sheet 1…...but I only want it to copy over if there is an "x" in the cell to the left of the data on sheets 2, 3 or 4.
What I am working on is a complex Task Tracker in excel. I want the various tasks throughout the book to move to a list on a "Priority Sheet" if I place an "X" in the box directly to the left of them (in whatever sheet they are currently in).
I am very new to all this but really trying to self educate. I am trying really hard to ask the question correctly. Please be gentle. I will get better. Excel 2016

Comment: Welcome to SO. What I would recommend is starting with something and asking questions when you get stuck rather than "how do I do this?". To get you started, I would suggest looking into VBA and the `Worksheet_Change` event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) which you would probably want on sheets 2,3 & 4 to know when to update worksheet 1... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I was trying to do. Here is the question I asked in SO. You will find my answer at the bottom of **copying data from a row on one excel sheet based on data in another column, to another sheet**. I hope this helps.